# getElementsByClassName adding style

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementsbyclassname

With this code I am looping through the `li` elements to add the class 'cool'. Just testing different methods such as `getElementById` and `querySelectorAll` and they work fine, but when I use `getElementsByClassName`, it skips every other one out, not applying the style to it. I removed the `i++` counter which applies it to every element, but wouldn't that lead to an infinite loop? Can anyone explain?

```
var listItems = document..getElementsByClassName('test');

var i;
for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) { //loop through elements //remove ++ when using .getElementsByClassName method to select each element
listItems[i].className = 'cool';// change class to cool
}
```

Comment: Isn't it because you have `document..getElementsByClassName('test');` with two **dots** instead of one? This would basically fail to execute and so the class wouldn't be added. Check your browser console (F12 on chrome)

Comment: why do you think it would cause an infinite loop

Comment: Sounds like it might be live nodelist issue. If you change the class name that element gets removed from the nodelist - therefore the loop skips over the next one.

Comment: the reason is `getElementsByClassName` returns a live list that will change if you change classname property of the element,one solution is looping backwards

Comment: @sahbeewah If he removes the `i++` then yes, the counter `i` won't increment anymore and therefore the loop will never end. If the code is executed, but I believe it would. (Meaning it's not a syntax error not to add the `i++` at the end)

Comment: When you change a class of an item, it is removed from this list, and all items slide left. So, after increasing `i` to 1, you actually access the **third** element, but not the **second**.

Comment: @Vadorequest If he removes `++`, it will work properly. The loop will end, because he will remove all items of this class, and node list will become empty.

Comment: Ah, right, even though you made a *copy* using `listItems`, since it's a copy by reference (because it's an object) then the copy would be altered on live. So @YeldarKurmangaliyev explanation is right. Another way going forward would be to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document.getElementsByClassName('test');))` so you get a copy by value and not by reference and you can use the `i++`.

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate all input